# php google app engine app yaml handler with'?'

Tags: .htaccess, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a php page that displays users' profiles. The file called **profile_full.php**.
In order to view each user's profile there is a link like this: **profile_full.php?email=1** for **user 1**, **profile_full.php?email=2** for **user 2** etc.

I use .htaccess file to cut the url address. Its is the follwoing:

```
# profile requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /profile_full.php?email=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So for the url if type **/1** get profile page for user 1, if type **/2** get profile page for user 2 etc. Tt works fine in my localhost at my laptop using XAMPP.

My problem is how to fix this my app.yaml file in order to make it work with google's app engine. This is my app.yaml that it is not working:

```
application: testing-my-app1  
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:


- url: /profile_full
  script: profile_full.php
```

any idea how to fix my handler? The error message get is The url "/1" does not match any handlers.

Comment: Why do you have "worket24"?

Comment: sorry just removed it... but still not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [link that includess .php? in google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680438/link-that-includess-php-in-google-app-engine)