# link that includess .php? in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, handler

I use app.yaml on google's app engine.

I have a link in my php file which is of this format: **profile.php?id=1**, which gives me the profile page for user 1. Any idea how to deal with this link in my app.yaml file? This is what I have done:

```
application: myappl-testing-858585  
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /profile.php?id=
  script: profile.php?id=
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `app.yaml` file should only route the paths, like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /profile
  script: profile.php
```

(Note that I also removed ".php" from the URL, since you really should not expose the internal file format like ".php", ".html", ".jsp", ".asp", etc. in your URLS... this is an implementation detail of your site, and it's both not good to bother users with it -- it makes for uglier URLs -- and it also makes it more difficult for you to modify your site in the future should you replace one implementation with another).

Then, in your *.php file, you simply use `$_GET` to test for the existence of / retrieve the ID.

In terms of your site structure, though, you may wish to consider changing the ID to a part of the path rather than a GET parameter if it is always a required parameter (just for URL nicety). In that case, you would register the handler like the following:

```
handlers:
- url: /profile/(\d+)
  script: profile.php
```

... so that your URLs  looked like "/profile/123" instead of "/profile?id=123".

Comment: ok thanks for your advice. Can you please check at my previous question which is in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680022/php-google-app-engine-app-yaml-handler-with

Comment: Your other question is effectively identical to this one, so I've voted to close the other one as a duplicate.

Comment: can you please check my previous question? I have change it to the way you told me but still not working?

Comment: In your other question, you want to handle a URL of the form /123 rather than /profile/123, in which case the "url" should be a matching regex like "/(\d+)".

Comment: change it to - url: /profile_full/(\d+) script: profile_full.php. Still nothing. Is there a problem because I use htaccess to cut the url?

Comment: App Engine doesn't support .htaccess. The first layer of routing is done by app.yaml, and then any additional routing is done within your own script.

Comment: so the problem is on the url cut that I have and in my htaccess file. Thanks